# How can I display a custom validation error using an observer?

Tags: magento-1, frontend-error

This is my code:

```
if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping')){
    $data = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('shipping');
    if (strlen($data['firstname']) > 2){
         // here throw an error 
    }
}
```

I am using this events :  `<sales_quote_save_before>`

I tried smth like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('test error.'));
```

but nothing is displayed when press the place order button in the checkout. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like the duplicate suggestion is correct. Closing.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code helpful to you

```
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
$controller->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
$response = array('error' => -1, 'message' => $helper->__('Error'));

return $controller->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```

Comment: I already tried this version :( and it is not working